# Scalar field theory boundary term in AdS

Tags: general-relativity, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, boundary-terms

In AdS we can have the following action

$$
S=\frac{1}{2}\int_\mathcal{M}{d^{d+1}x\sqrt{-g}\phi(g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu+m^2)\phi}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathcal{M}}d^{d+1}x\sqrt{-g}\partial_\mu(g^{\mu\nu}\phi\partial_\nu\phi)
$$
where the second term can be written as
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}{d^{d}x'\sqrt{-h}\phi n^\mu\partial_\mu\phi}
$$
where the surface term is written in terms of the induced metric. My problem is understanding this surface term written in terms of the induced metric. I am not sure what the vector $n^\mu$ is and how to compute it.

Say we have the AdS metric (in Poincare coordinates) given by
$$
ds^2=\frac{b^2}{z^2}(dz^2+dx_\mu dx^\mu)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\mu=0,\ldots,d-1
$$
How can we compute $h_{ab}$ and $n^\mu$? The induced metric is given by
$$
h_{ab}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^a}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^b}g_{\mu\nu}
$$ but I don't understand how to use this.

Comment: $n$ is the outgoing unit normal to the boundary so in your coordinates this is $n=-\frac{z}{b} \partial_z$. BTW, if you're having trouble with these basic things in GR you should take a look at Poisson's book which explains how calculations are done in GR (as opposed to the formal aspects which are covered in other GR books).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Can you link me the book?

Comment: http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/poisson-rel-toolkit.pdf